# Filtering table data using multiple columns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a filter/search table and I am using the JavaScript from [this site.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Here's the script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can change which column to be used as the filter by changing the index in "td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")***[0]***;"

0 means the first column will be used, 1 means the second column, etc.

Using the same script, how can I use multiple columns to be the filter?

**EDIT:**

This is the tableinside my 'exampletable.php':

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onKeyUp="myFunction()" placeholder="Search"

<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">

 
<?php
    include 'connection.php'; //to connect to my database, "database"
    
    $data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT*FROM database;");
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
?>
                      
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    
          <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Name</th>
              <th class="text-center">Age</th>
              <th class="text-center">Hobby</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>

          <tr>
              <td class="text-center"><?php echo $d['name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $d['age']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $d['hobby']; ?></td>
          </tr>

    </table>

          <?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I have the column "Name, Age, and Hobby" using the function inside the JavaScript, if the index is 0 (the index for the filter column) then the first column (Name) will be used as the filter.

For example, when I type "Catherine" in the search bar, then the page will only show the data with "Catherine" inside the Name column.

What I wanted to do is to use say both Name and Hobby column as the filter. So, say when I type "Cat" in the search bar, then the page will only show the data with "Cat" inside the Name and also Hobby column.

Comment: DIdn't understand question. Can you please send your html?

Comment: Okay, I edited the question. Let me know if it helps. @TariqAhmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another for loop to evaluate all tds (columns) will help you with that.

This might be helpful:

```
// This variable switch if the filter catch any result
    var isset = false;

    //This loop evalaute all rows
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //Here we search for all columns in this row
        //note that we get rid of [0] at the end because we're looking for all
        //tds, not just the first one
        let tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        //Here we evaluate each column for this row
        for (let td of tds) {
            //If td has a value
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
                    isset = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //The decision of show or hide the row is made here because
        //the loop has to evaluate all columns before decide if show or hide the entire row
        if (isset) {
            //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            //If the filter catch no result, we hide the row
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        //This is to reset the variable for the next loop
        isset = false;
    }
```

Your entire function will be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    // This variable switch if the filter catch any result
    var isset = false;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // This variable switch if the filter catch any result
    var isset = false;

    //This loop evalaute all rows
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //Here we search for all columns in this row
        //note that we get rid of [0] at the end because we're looking for all
        //tds, not just the first one
        let tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        //Here we evaluate each column for this row
        for (let td of tds) {
            //If td has a value
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
                    isset = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //The decision of show or hide the row is made here because
        //the loop has to evaluate all columns before decide if show or hide the entire row
        if (isset) {
            //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            //If the filter catch no result, we hide the row
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        //This is to reset the variable for the next loop
        isset = false;
    }
}
```

I have tested the code with this script

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onKeyUp="myFunction()" placeholder="Search">



<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Age</th>
            <th class="text-center">Hobby</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Alejandro</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Football</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Peralta</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Alejandro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Casemiro</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Soccer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Moreno</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Tenis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Alejandro</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Moreno</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    // This variable switch if the filter catch any result
    var isset = false;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // This variable switch if the filter catch any result
    var isset = false;

    //This loop evalaute all rows
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //Here we search for all columns in this row
        //note that we get rid of [0] at the end because we're looking for all
        //tds, not just the first one
        let tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        //Here we evaluate each column for this row
        for (let td of tds) {
            //If td has a value
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
                    isset = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //The decision of show or hide the row is made here because
        //the loop has to evaluate all columns before decide if show or hide the entire row
        if (isset) {
            //If the filter catch any result, we show the row
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            //If the filter catch no result, we hide the row
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        //This is to reset the variable for the next loop
        isset = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This solved my problem, though I can't choose which column to use which is fine, I will try to find the way to do just that later. But I noticed that by using your js script, the table headers (Name, Age, Hobby) are missing after I perform a search. I tried to compare it with my script from before and alter your script a bit but I kept making a mess as I just started to learn JS. My only guess that it has to do with deleting the index or in the tds loop.

Comment: I just edit the test to add a tbody to table. The headers were missing because the filter was searching through all rows, header rows too. So I put 'id' into the tbody and filter only those rows inside the tbody. Read more about <tbody>: The Table Body element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody